# How to generate XSD files for web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I need to create web service (.NET) which will be used by other system.
In order for them to implement logic which will use my web service, I need to send them wsdl and XSD files for my web service.

WSDL file is not a problem, I will obtain it from .asmx page by passing wsdl parameter.
But how can I generate appropriate XSD files for my web service?
Can I use XSD.exe tool and pass it .wsdl file as parameter, or is there another way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the [disco.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy2a3ybs.aspx) utility which allows you to save the wsdl and xsd files on disk so that those files could be used to generate a client proxy without having access to the WSDL web address.

Comment: I have succeeded to generate XSD files with this tool, cheers.

Comment: I am not able to generate xsd from wsdl web address.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Pro edition of visual studio (and above), when opening a XML file you will find an XML menu, with an item that will generate an XSD from it (Create Schema). I believe it uses `xsd.exe` under the hood though.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302298.aspx#xmltools_topic3).

Comment: When I try this I get following error:"The supplied xml instance is a schema or contains an inline schema. This class cannot infer a schema for a schema."

Comment: @buhtla - apparently, a schema is already defined. Look at the XML and see if it links to a schema.

Comment: I am trying to generate XSD from WSDL file. WSDL is generated automatically from web service I have created in Visual Studio - so eather Web Service generate invalid XML (which I doubt) or there is some other reason for this error I get.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "?xsd=1" at the end of the service url to get schema.

i.e. If your web service URL is 
://my_ws_service:9080/service/name
then you can get WSDL using
://my_ws_service:9080/service/name?WSDL
and you can get schema using 
://my_ws_service:9080/service/name?xsd=1
( note xsd is case sensitive)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd share my solution, in my case I needed to create an actual C# class so I could use it to deserialize the response XML for a given endpoint whose WSDL I had saved on my dev PC.

I opened up Visual Studio Command Prompt and typed the following:

```
wsdl "name-of-your-file"
```

Where the name-of-your-file is the name of your saved WSDL file.  Running the command should generate a C# class that you can then use in your client applicaiton to deserialize an XML SOAP Response for your given endpoint.

Hope this helps.