# Calling a webservice (asmx) from different language

Tags: java, .net, xsd, wsdl, asmx

from a non technical intermediary I got a question for a number of files (.xsd and .wsdl) for an external organization that wil be using our webservice.

This is de first time for me that i've written a webservice for an external party that wil be using a different technique other than .NET (it will be java).

as read in the post: [How to generate XSD files for web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177309/how-to-generate-xsd-files-for-web-service) I think only sending the wsdl file wil be sufficient.

Can someone tell me if i'm right. If not so. How do i generate a fitting xsd with this wsdl?

Comment: First of all, are you aware that ASMX is a legacy technology and should not be used for new development?

Comment: Yes I am, i'm already studying WCF, reason I'm still using asmx is because it already existed and only is updated internally (but there are some extra parameters exposed on the outside and theredor the contract will change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I know, exposing WSDL is enough.
Every language able to read wsdl could create proxies, wrappers and/or classes to make it easier to access/consume your webservice.
As described in [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language)

> The WSDL describes services as collections of network endpoints, or
>   ports. The WSDL specification provides an XML format for documents for
>   this purpose. The abstract definitions of ports and messages are
>   separated from their concrete use or instance, allowing the reuse of
>   these definitions. A port is defined by associating a network address
>   with a reusable binding, and a collection of ports defines a service.
>   Messages are abstract descriptions of the data being exchanged, and
>   port types are abstract collections of supported operations. The
>   concrete protocol and data format specifications for a particular port
>   type constitutes a reusable binding, where the operations and messages
>   are then bound to a concrete network protocol and message format. In
>   this way, WSDL describes the public interface to the Web service.
>
> WSDL
>   is often used in combination with SOAP and an XML Schema to provide
>   Web services over the Internet. A client program connecting to a Web
>   service can read the WSDL file to determine what operations are
>   available on the server. Any special datatypes used are embedded in
>   the WSDL file in the form of XML Schema. The client can then use SOAP
>   to actually call one of the operations listed in the WSDL file using
>   XML or HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Just expose a test url to them. You should do that anyway for them to be able to really test things as they develop their client. After this is done it's just a matter of getting them to retrieve http://[insert url]?wsdl

Comment: This should only be done once the contract has been decided upon and once it will no longer change.